# I'm forcing SSL with htaccess but it isn't working with URLs that link to files

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, ssl, redirect, https

I realised that my site is not redirecting correctly when the URL link to a file (a pdf in this case). The others urls of my site are working perfectly. This is my htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

It's strange because after differents ways of typing my url I found this:

- If I type "myweb.com/urltopdf", it is redirected to "https://myweb.com/urltopdf"
- If I type "https://myweb.com/urltopdf", URL works
- If I type "http://myweb.com/urltopdf", it isn't redirected and the url doesn't work. This case is my problem.

I dont know if it's important but I am using laravel 5.2.

Thanks.

EDIT: It works on firefox and edge but not on chrome.

Comment: Try using **Trusted Proxies** https://github.com/fideloper/TrustedProxy

Comment: So the only problem is the last case, is that right?  And in that case `the url doesn't work` - what does that mean, exactly?  Any error msg?  Note that 301 redirects are cached by the browser, so are hard to debug because if you change it the change might not be visible in the browser as the previous version is cached.  AFAIK 302 does not behave like that, so at least while testing you could use 302 to avoid that.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I'm using 302 now. When I say the url doesn´t work I mean that nothing happens. I open a new tab, enter the url and nothing happens. I stay at new tab  page. I tried to delete browser cache but still not working.

Comment: *Something* happens, you just need to find out what :-) Does the browser keep loading, and eventually time out?  What do your logs say - your Laravel log is at `storage/logs/laravel.log`, also check your PHP and Apache logs.